# CSS / JS for image-in-grid alternative for radio button selector?

Tags: css, image, widget, radio-button, reflow

Are there any CSS toolkits that let you reproduce radio button functionality but using photos / images laid out in a grid? For example, a grid of auto models on a rental car site, where the user needs to select a preferred vehicle for their rental application by clicking on the car's picture.

This is similar to HTML selection menu widgets, except:

- The layout is a grid, not a line of items (i.e. needs to wrap).
- The currently-selected item is persistent and always visible, optionally with a checkmark (or other icon-based indicator to show selection)
- It would be great if the grid laid itself out intelligently (recalculates rows and columns) when the browser resizes.
- It would also be nice to have the option to choose between single-selection (radio button) and multiple-selection (checkbox button) modes.

I thought this would be straightforward but I've had a really hard time finding anything like this. The [JQuery UI button functionality](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#icons) is close but (I think) doesn't provide image-centric buttons or a reflowing grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. You wrap each of your cars in a `DIV`, put a checkbox inside, and then wrap the image in a `label` for the checkbox. Clicking on the image checks the box.

The jQuery then changes the class of the wrapping `DIV` to selected so that you can style it to make it obvious that the car is selected.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $('input:checkbox').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.photo').toggleClass('selected');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="photo">
    <input type="checkbox" name="image[0][status]" value="1" />
    <label for="image[0][status]">
        <img src="#" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: That is great! I didn't know about the label-for combo. Thanks!